# Remove data from array according to the second one

Tags: php, arrays

I have array that contain - name, email, and ID
I have second array that contain the same parameters, but with different data

I would like to remove all the cells, from the first array, where the emails don't exist in the second array.
For instance -
first array:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Shlomi green' (length=25)
      'email' => string 'shlomig$mail.co.il' (length=25)
      'contactID' => string '28' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Roi Keen' (length=21)
      'email' => string 'roi@mail.com' (length=16)
      'contactID' => string '53' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Ronen' (length=8)
      'email' => string 'ronen$mail.com' (length=23)
      'contactID' => string '43' (length=2)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Shlomi' (length=10)
      'email' => string 'shlomi$mail.co.il' (length=17)
      'contactID' => string '54' (length=2)
```

Second array:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Shlomi green' (length=25)
      'email' => string 'shlomig$mail.co.il' (length=25)
      'contactID' => string '28' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Ronen' (length=8)
      'email' => string 'ronen$mail.com' (length=23)
      'contactID' => string '43' (length=2)
```

Only "shlomig$mail.co.il" and "ronen$mail.com" will stay i the first array

Comment: better you could use second array itself.

Comment: what is your expected result ?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

See below, the in-line comments should explain it well enough.

```
// First populate a single dimension array with
// all of the email addresses in the second array
$keepEmails = [];
foreach($arrB as $keyB=>$valueB) {
    $keepEmails[] = $valueB['email'];
}

// Then iterate through the first array
foreach ($arrA as $keyA=>$valueA) {
    // If email is not in the keepEmails array, then remove
    if (!in_array($valueA['email'], $keepEmails)) { 
        unset($arrA[$keyA]);
    }
}

// Re-key the array (so the key values are sequential)
$arrA = array_values($arrA);
```

---

If you use array_intersect, take heed of the note in the PHP docs:

> **Note:** Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1
>   === (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same.

Comment: can I use "array_intersect" ?

Comment: @Roi Yes you can but be careful of the value comparison, see my updated answer.

Comment: @Roi Maybe you would get more help if you would read and take a look at the comments under your question

Comment: @Rio Rizier123 is right, you should look at the comments particularly 'better you could use second array itself.' I assumed that the first array was going to have other entries in the sub-arrays which i why you weren't using the second array, but if you are talking about using array_interesect then that can't be the case. You need to expand on your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can user `array_intersect` if your values are String.

However, in case your values relate to different string representation, although you wanted some of them to be considered as equal, you should take a look at [`array_uintersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php). Thanks to this method, it's possible to use a custom comparison function as a callback.